# Ignite 2.11.0 not able see data using SqlFieldsQuery and DBeaver using JDBC nor from REST

Tags: jdbc, ignite, dbeaver

We recently upgraded Apache Ignite from 2.8.1 to 2.11.0. Data load is fine,but data is not accessible using SqlFieldsQuery, DBeaver and REST. All I'm seeing is empty results. Tried both thick and thin client. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Do you see any error messages, either on one of the server nodes or DBeaver? Do you see anything in DBeaver, like I would expect to see at least the SYS schema. I just did a superficial test, and it worked correctly.

Comment: @Stephen SYS views were coming fine. Issue is with custom caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue exists in thin client data streamer. Moved to thick client data streamer issue is resolved now.